# An application wants to access the private key but its locked - SSH

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

For logging into my shared hosting server using ssh, I have generated the public/private key, authorised the public key, then downloaded the public and private key and finally moved those keys to the .ssh folder on my desktop which is running ubuntu.

Following are the permissions for my keys:

-rw-rw-r-- id_rsa

-rw-rw-r-- id_rsa.pub

When I try to ssh into my server, I am being asked for a password with a prompt that says "An application wants to access the private key but its locked".

I tried my login password but its not working. What am I missing here?

(reposted from stackoverflow)

Comment: ...and what are the permissions of the $HOME/.ssh directory? The .ssh folder on your desktop is completely irrelevant and will not be used (unless you did some questionable things to ssh itself).

Comment: jvb - the permission of .ssh directory is rwx------

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Gnome Keyring SSH Agent](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/Ssh) wiki, there are three ways to achieve this:

- Use the "Startup Applications" capplet (ie: gnome-session-properties) and disable the "SSH Key Agent" startup program.
- Build gnome-keyring without SSH support using this configure option: `./configure --disable-ssh-agent`
- If you're starting gnome-keyring manually or from a script you can use the --components option to exclude starting up the SSH support: `gnome-keyring-daemon --components keyring,pkcs11`

Comment: +1; First bullet worked for me on Xubuntu - however capplet name is (Alt+F2): xfce4-session-settings and 'Launch GNOME services on startup' must be also unchecked in 'Advanced' tab.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is happening because the `gnome-keyring` daemon is managing the
ssh keys (it shouldn't since ssh already has an agent).
You can tell the daemon to stop doing this by issuing this command:

```
sudo gconftool-2 --set -t bool /apps/gnome-keyring/daemon-components/ssh false
```

I have also seen this version of the command ([source](https://gist.github.com/sandys/3979772)) :

```
sudo gconftool-2 --direct --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory --type bool --set /apps/gnome-keyring/daemon-components/ssh FALSE
```

Comment: harrymc - I used the commands but its still asking for the password. When I run sudo gconftool-2 --get /apps/gnome-keyring/daemon-components/ssh, it returns false.

Comment: Did you try the other commands from the link?

Comment: Yes i tried all those commands.

Comment: Gnome is a moving target, and gnome-keyring is unmaintained, so it's difficult to find a permanent solution. Try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/786722) for a workaround by respawning gnome-keyring-daemon, and for removing ssh as component of Gnome keyring.

Comment: Its not working. I will try it the other way around  - generate the keys locally and then upload the public key on to the ssh folder on the server. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For me, below solution worked, Added the private key to ssh-agent

```
$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
> Agent pid 59566

$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was not the *password* for the host or the server it wanted, but the *passphrase* that I provided when I generated the key.